# Save BigDecimal in jpa

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa, mariadb, bigdecimal

I use spring jpa and hibernate 4 for the implementation.

In a object, I have a bigDecimal field.

Before saving this field, I see the value: 0.09975.

When it's saved in mariadb, the value is 0.10.

In my objet

```
private BigDecimal tvqRate;
```

Jpa have created the table automatically

```
like a decimal
column size is 19, 
2 decimal digits.
```

I use spring data repository to save object.

How to save correctly the value?

Comment: where is your column definition, and what annotations/XML have you specified for the field?

Comment: I just specified the type of the objet and jpa have created all the rest.

Comment: maybe will need to put something like @Column(precision=6, scale=5) to be able to save something like 0.09975

Comment: maybe you do, and what happens when you try it? those attributes affect the generation of schema, so you have to perform that part

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'div_precision_increment';`  `SHOW CREATE TABLE`